# Calucalted colum in list on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column, date

Hope you're well;

Can I have help with the following SharePoint list, I would like the expiry alert date column to automatically update to 6 months post the contract expiry date column;

Is possible to do . How do I do it.

[image]

kind regards,
Anees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Calculated column to store the expiry alert date, then add the following into formula setting:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Column1]),MONTH([Column1])+6,DAY([Column1]))
```

Note: You need to change Column1 to your contract expiry date column.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good day!

Here is a source for some syntax around calculated columns!

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3

For your problem, you want to add 6 months contract expiry date. Here is the formula:

=DATE(YEAR([ContactExpiry Date]),MONTH([ContactExpiry Date])+6,DAY([ContactExpiry Date]))

Hope that helps!

Comment: Where do add the formula in ?

Comment: I get error message when I add in the formula

Comment: My guess is my column name  is not exactly like your column name. If you look at the right section of the screen, there is a text area that shows the existing columns of the list/library. You can find your column in there. In the [ ] of the formula, make sure the desired column is exactly typed in as you see it in the right most section. Screenshots will help solve the issues as well.

Comment: it has worked :)